# How to add metadata nodes using the LLVM C Api/llvm-fs bindings

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, code-generation, llvm, llvm-fs

I'm trying to add metadata nodes to a program, either onto the instructions or as global metadata. How do I do this with the LLVM C API? It now provides a function [`LLVMAddNamedMetadataOperand`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8cpp_source.html#l00601) (as found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998367/how-do-i-create-named-metadata-via-the-llvm-c-api)) but I can't seem to see how to use it. This is bound to `addNamedMetadataOperand` in the [llvm-fs](https://github.com/keithshep/llvm-fs) bindings. I tried this:

```
addNamedMetadataOperand myModule "foobar" (mDString "cat" 3u)
```

expecting it to make some metadata node called `foobar` but it doesn't work - complains about cast errors. I thought maybe you were supposed to use `addNamedMetadataOperand` on an instruction, so I tried:

```
let ret = buildRet bldr (constInt i32 0UL)
addNamedMetadataOperand myModule "foobar" ret
```

but it didn't like this either.

Comment: Hey callum, if you add a bug report to llvm-fs (or email the google group) with full code I'll try to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Hey Keith, I don't even know if this is the right way to do it, or how to add any kind of metadata using the C API/fs-bindings. If this is the correct way to make some metadata then it is a bug and I'll provide a minimal example on GH.

Comment: Honestly I don't know either. It's not a part of the API I've looked into yet, but full source code is the easiest way for me to start looking into it even if the result is "not a bug"

Comment: Keith: Take a look at this example of what I'm trying: https://github.com/CRogers/llvm-fs-metadata-test, specifically https://github.com/CRogers/llvm-fs-metadata-test/blob/master/llvm-fs-metadata-test/Program.fs

Comment: I poked around for a while in the C source and documentation and didn't find anything wrong with what you were doing (I tried using getFirstInstruction incase that was necessary and it had the same outcome). I might have to work my way backward from working C++ code to see what's going on so it could be a while until I get to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added two new "F# friendly functions": mdNode and mdNodeInContext in [this commit](https://github.com/keithshep/llvm-fs/commit/1b8c7c6726094112b45c1fdc78f68364b96037fe). With that commit I can modify your example code to:

```
open LLVM.Core
open LLVM.Generated.Core
open LLVM.Generated.BitWriter

let i32 = int32Type ()
let i32zero = constInt i32 0UL false

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    // Set up the module/function
    let module_ = moduleCreateWithName "foobar"
    //let context = getModuleContext module_
    let funcTy = functionType i32 [||]
    let func = addFunction module_ "main" funcTy
    let bldr = createBuilder ()

    let entry = appendBasicBlock func "entry"
    positionBuilderAtEnd bldr entry

    // Make a Metadata node and try and attach it to a ret
    //let mdnode = mDStringInContext context "bazquux" 7u
    let mdstring = mDString "bazquux" 7u
    let ret = buildRet bldr i32zero
    // From http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1LLVMContext.html
    // MD_dbg = 0, MD_tbaa = 1, MD_prof = 2, MD_fpmath = 3, MD_range = 4, MD_tbaa_struct = 5
    // Fails here
    //setMetadata ret 0u mdnode
    let myMDName = "my_MD_kind"
    setMetadata ret (getMDKindID myMDName (uint32 myMDName.Length)) (mdNode [|mdstring|])

    // Save bitcode to file
    writeBitcodeToFile module_ "metadatatest.bc"
```

Which gives the bitcode:

```
; ModuleID = 'metadatatest.bc'

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  ret i32 0, !my_MD_kind !0
}

!0 = metadata !{metadata !"bazquux"}
```

I used getMDKindID rather than one of the pre-defined MD kinds because when I was using 0u I was getting no metadata output. I haven't looked deep into why but from looking at http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#metadata it seems that the predefined metadata types have some constraints that the instruction it was applied to wasn't meeting. Anyhow, let me know if you see more problems with this. It's not a part of the API that I'm using at the moment but I do want it to work as well as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has turned out really useful :)